# Why is my Hard Decision Decoding of Convolutional codes not performing well?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, convolution, viterbi-algorithm

I am encoding and decoding a randomly generated bitstream of data using a [5 7] convolutional code. For the decoding part I am using a Viterbi Decoder and trying both HDD and SDD. However, my results for HDD seem incorrect as the BER exceeds the theoretical upper bound that I have calculated. I used a bitstream of 100,000 bits. Any help as to why this is happening? I know that SDD is superior to HDD but shouldn't HDD also be below the Upper Bound? Here are the results:

[image: HDD]

[image: SDD]

Here is my function for Viterbi Decoding using HDD:

```
function decodedBits = viterbiDecoderAWGN_HARD(receivedBits, L, k, n, G)
    % Viterbi Decoder for a (2,1) convolutional code
    % receivedBits: Received bit sequence
    % L: Constraint length
    % k: Number of input bits (always 1 for a rate 1/2 code)
    % n: Number of output bits (always 2 for a rate 1/2 code)
    % G: Generator matrix in octal form

    % Generate Trellis structure
    [nextState, outputTable] = generateTrellis(L, k, n, G);

    numStates = 2^(L-1);
    numInputs = 2^k; % Always 2 for binary
    numSteps = length(receivedBits) / n;

    % Initialize path metrics and survivors
    pathMetrics = inf(numStates, numSteps+1);
    pathMetrics(1,1) = 0; % Start state assumed to be 0
    survivors = zeros(numStates, numSteps);
    
    % Convert BPSK symbols to binary digits for hard decision
    hardDecisionBits = receivedBits > 0; % Convert to 0s and 1s based on the threshold

    % Viterbi algorithm
    for step = 1:numSteps
        receivedSymbol = hardDecisionBits((step-1)*n+1:step*n);
        for currentState = 0:(numStates-1)
            for inputBit = 0:(numInputs-1)
                next = nextState(currentState+1, inputBit+1);
                encodedSymbol = de2bi(outputTable(currentState+1, inputBit+1), n, 'left-msb');
                hammingDistance = sum(xor(encodedSymbol, receivedSymbol));
                
                metric = pathMetrics(currentState+1, step) + hammingDistance;
                if metric < pathMetrics(next+1, step+1)
                    pathMetrics(next+1, step+1) = metric;
                    survivors(next+1, step) = currentState+1; % MATLAB indexing
                end
            end
        end
    end

    % Traceback
    decodedBits = zeros(1, numSteps);
    [~, currentState] = min(pathMetrics(:, end)); % Finding the end state with the lowest metric
    for step = numSteps:-1:1
        decodedBits(step) = find([nextState(survivors(currentState, step),:)+1] == currentState, 1) - 1;
        currentState = survivors(currentState, step);
    end
end
```

I am sure that the Trellis is being generated correctly so there is no problem there. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the upper bound come from? And: your curves seem a bit too wiggly, have you really tried with enough sufficiently random data and sufficiently independently random noise?

Comment: It's a union bound. It comes from the transfer function once I sent its derivative with respect to N equal to zero. Yes, at high SNR they do become a bit wiggly but I guess 100k bits should suffice. In terms of randomness I generate 999990 bits randomly and then append 10 zeros for termination. I ran the simulation many times and with different sized input arrays and still the BER for HDD always exceeds the bounds.

Comment: I mean, 100k bits when your BER is in the order of 0.5·10⁻⁴ is of course pretty questionable, but point taken, that's not the part of the curve you're worried about. I'm not sure how you calculate the Union Bound – the usual problem with the union bound is that it's an infinite sum, and truncation turns it to be something that isn't quite a bound any more (but I doubt that should be leading what we see here).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I used a million bits and got smoother curves albeit after a long time of waiting but thanks for that suggestion. However, the problem with HDD still persists! If you want I can share the calculations for the Upper Bound...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accounting for quantization noise in your calculation of the bound when decoding with HDD?

One-bit representation is a special case anyway, but the quantization noise has an impact, generally. For the special case of one-bit quantizers, as SNR increases it is increasingly likely that hard decision errors amplify the noise and by larger amounts compared to AWGN variance. That is, a hard decision error most likely happens with the noise barely crossing the zero threshold. The hard decision "amplifies" the noise that caused the threshold crossing by quantizing to +1 or -1, even though the unquantized value was very close to zero (but slightly over the boundary). The likelihood of large amplification from close-to-zero to +1 or -1 becomes worse for higher SNR (i.e. rarer HD errors).

Comment: I actually used the same bound for both and your answer makes me think that might not be ideal. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. As I noted, the single-bit quantizer has more nuance than multi-bit. Assuming you did your union bound from min-distance error events (e.g. from pair-state trellis or other analysis of the CC), you can approximate the effects of multi-bit quantization by adding the quantizer variance to the noise variance. Then, lower the number of bits to see how it changes as you get near 1 bit. For multi-bit quantizers, the AWGN plus quantization error still has largely Gaussian tails.